# Changing hover text in histogram bins plotly

Tags: python, r, plotly

I am trying to change the hovertext for histogram plots created by plotly. By default, it creates (bin - bin, frequency) on hover. I would like to annotate it so it's something like the following:

Bins: bin - bin
Frequency: frequency

I currently cannot figure out how to target the histogram variables so I can change the text attribute.

The following is example code:

```
library(plotly)
test <- data.frame(x = rnorm(50))

plot_ly(test, x = ~x, type = "histogram", mode = "text", text = paste("Bins:", "</br>Frequency:"))
```

Comment: What code are you using to create the plot?

Comment: Added example code to generate the plot in R, what I am looking for should likely be the same across different plotly platforms

Comment: did you solve it? having the same issue here

Comment: Never ended up solving the issue unfortunately.